# Beautiful soup find_all() returning an empty list for a div but Developer tools in Chrome clearly shows elements inside div

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use web-scraping to pull example sentences for Japanese vocabulary words from this site https://www.kanshudo.com/collections/wikipedia_jlpt/WPJLPT-N3-1
to create a deck of flash cards.

I'm trying to unit test my code on the first word on the page "人気" by pulling the elements under the div with class = "tatoeba" (tatoeba means "example" in Japanese) nested under the div with id jukugo_119971.  The div id = "jukugo_119971" demarcates the elements for "人気".  Even though the developer tools in Chrome show there are elements under the "tatoeba" div, my code returns an empty list and I cannot figure out why.

My code is below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import pandas as pd
import requests
import re
import bs4
import unicodedata
url = 'https://www.kanshudo.com/collections/wikipedia_jlpt/WPJLPT-N3-1'
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
response.raise_for_status()
soup= BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")
word = 'jukugo_119971'
print(soup.find('div', id=word).find_all('div',class_='tatoeba'))
```

You can see in the screenshot of the developer tools window (following link) the elements I'm trying to pull/reference.
Screenshot of the developer tools window for the elements in the "tatoeba" div

[image]

Please advise.  I'm very new to web-scraping (first project) and feel quite lost.  Please let me know if I can provide any other information. Thank you.

Comment: I think the data is being loaded by Javascript. You cannot get the data using ```beautifulsoup```. Use ```selenium```

Answer (score 1):

You can use selenium along with a web driver before making the soup of your page.

First download a webdriver for example Chrome webdriver from the link: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads, Please ensure that the downloaded version is same as the chrome version installed in your pc.

Next, place the webdriver file in the directory where the code/.py/.ipynb file is present.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep

options= Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options)
url= "https://www.kanshudo.com/collections/wikipedia_jlpt/WPJLPT-N3-1"

driver.get(url)
sleep(1)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
```

Download the above mentioned libraries according to your environment and then find your desired tags from the soup.

Comment: thanks Hamza, I'll take a look at your solution today